# Firebase Cloud Messaging x Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase

Qual diferença entre o Firebase Cloud Messaging e o Google Cloud Messaging?

Ambos são gratuitos?

Quem mantém o Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Qual seria a melhor opção?

Comment: Ambos são gratuitos, mantidos pelo google, o FCM é uma versão melhorada do GCM, assim como o google substituiu o C2DM pelo GCM, se for criar um projeto novo é melhor utilizar o FCM.

Comment: Obrigada. Pergunto: 1 - O GCM foi descontinuado? 2 - O FCM seria tipo um Push Notifications da Apple?

Comment: @LuizaCH verifiquei que você já fez cerca de 40 perguntas e nunca marcou uma resposta como correta – apesar de ter recebido muitas respostas boas. Você deve aceitar a resposta que te ajuda a resolver o problema, para que todos entendam isso e para valorizar a pessoa que te ajudou com pontos de reputação. Continue a fazer boas perguntas mas não se esqueça da sua responsabilidade depois http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Comment: Luhhh conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 2):

> Qual diferença entre o firebase cloud messaging e o google cloud
>   messaging?

O *Firebase Cloud Messaging* (**FCM**) é uma solução de mensagens entre plataformas que permite a entrega confiável de mensagens e notificações sem custo.

O **FCM** é a nova versão do *Google Cloud Messaging* (**GCM**). Ele herda a infra-estrutura **GCM** confiável e escalável, além de novos recursos!

> Ambos são gratuitos?

Sim. Depois que o Google substituiu C2DM com GCM, tiraram todos os limites.

> Quem mantém o fcm?

Google

> Qual seria a melhor opção?

A resposta está na primeira pergunta. O FCM basicamente é o novo GCM porém com mais recursos.

#### Detalhes

- [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=pt-br)
- [Historical Overview - GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm#history)

Comment: Obrigada. Pergunto: 1 - O GCM foi descontinuado? 2 - O FCM seria tipo um Push Notifications da Apple?

Comment: "O GCM foi descontinuado?" R: Na [própria página](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) do Google eles aconselham fortemente usar o FCM. Então isso quer dizer que não a ideia é descontinuar o GCM.  "O FCM seria tipo um Push Notifications da Apple?" R:Sim